# main.CRITICAL: Error: Call to a member function isVirtual() on null

Tags: php, magento2.4.6

I am having this strange error filling my cron logs:

```
main.CRITICAL: Error: Call to a member function isVirtual() on null
```

from file

```
magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Rule/Condition/Address.php line 177
```

I can't figure out from where it is coming.

Any help please how to look for?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check this function:

```
    public function validate(\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $model)
{
    $address = $model;
    if (!$address instanceof \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address) {
        if ($model->getQuote()->isVirtual()) {
            $address = $model->getQuote()->getBillingAddress();
        } else {
            $address = $model->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
        }
    }

    if ('payment_method' == $this->getAttribute() && !$address->hasPaymentMethod()) {
        $address->setPaymentMethod($model->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethod());
    }

    return parent::validate($address);
}
```

It seems time to time your `$model->getQuote()` returns null. Hence it cannot call `$model->getQuote()->isVirtual()`.

Check your sales rule, one of them should be throwing this error.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I am checking my rules. You mean I need to look if there any Virtual products in my catalog first? And then to check my $model